# How to restore settings in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

I learn that in order to restore settings in TexStudio, I need to do `Menu > Options > Save/Load profile`. However, I find that `Load profile` can not restore settings like `Syntax highlight`, `favorite symbols` and many others.

I find in order to restore the complete settings, it needs to backup %APPDATA%\texstudio folder first and remove the folder. (I can not find texstudio.ini file in the same folder for TexStudio 4.2.3.) Then reinstall TexStudio and restore the backup folder.

Only in this way, I can restore the complete settings. I wonder if this is a correct procedure or if there is a bug in TexStudio or whatever the problem.

Comment: Options -> Reset all settings to thei defaults

Comment: I want to restore to all the previous settings, not the default ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, I believe how it works is to backup `%APPDATA%\texstudio` folder on the old machine first (normally on `AppData\Roaming\Texstudio` on Windows). Then after installing TexStudio on the new machine, copy this folder to the `%APPDATA%\texstudio` and it is done. In this way, entire settings on the old machine can be transferred to the new machine.

**Edit:**
It only needs to backup `%APPDATA%\texstudio\texstudio.ini` file (configuration settings). After installing TexStudio, just copy `texstudio.ini` to the `%APPDATA%\texstudio` folder and it is done.